# Спозиционировать 2 картинки в CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

пытаюсь сверстать по макету и никак не получается разместить 2 картинки нужным образом. Первый раз обращаюсь за помощью, поэтому камнями не кидайтесь.Собственно сможет кто помочь сделать так, чтобы эти 2 картинки были на одном уровне по горизонтали с уже заданными отступами.

```css
.party {
  width: 420px;
  height: 279px;
  padding: 135px 60px 32px 150px;
  float: left;
}

.coffee {
  width: 419px;
  height: 280px;
  float: right;
  padding: 135px 60px 32px 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div><img class="party" src="http://via.placeholder.com/420x279"></div>
  <div><img class="coffee" src="http://via.placeholder.com/419x280"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пора бы уже забыть о `float`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  width:90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.parent div {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/420x279"></div>
  <div class=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/419x280"></div>
</div>
```